# jQuery Mobile "pagebeforechange" being called twice

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following listener set up for "pagebeforechange" (very similar to the jQuery Mobile Documentation's own code) and a link on the home page that is calling http://localhost/#product?id=255979

```
//Bind Listener for Product Details
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    //Only Run If Site is Initialized
    if( ajaxSite.options.initialized ) {
        if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
            var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ),
                pl = /^#product/;

            if ( u.hash.search(pl) !== -1 ) {
                console.log("showProduct being called.");
                ajaxSite.showProduct( u, data.options );
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I open up the JavaScript console and click the link I am seeing the following:

```
showProduct being called.
showProduct being called.
```

I can't seem to find anything about why it would be getting called twice. I have seen other errors where vclicks get registered twice due to edge-clicking, but this doesn't make any sense since it is relying on the actual page change.

Comment: Are you running a multipage or single page layout? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/index.html The reason I ask is you're binding to $(document) instead of the pageId

Comment: Multiple Page Layout - the "showProduct()" method loads information onto the 2nd page, then transitions.

Comment: I wonder since you're binding the $(document) it's being called multiple times, could you just use the pageId instead and test?

Comment: That's it - there is a search page as well, and even though it has a different Page ID and was not "active", it was causing it to call twice. Not sure why the inactive page was causing the event to register, but that is an entirely different issue all together. Thank's very much. Kind of went blank after staring at it for hours :-). If you want to throw together an answer I would love to give you a correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're binding to the $(document) and using a Multi-page layout

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/index.html

I think jQM is loading the document multiple times (Just a hunch)

Switch to using the pageId instead, example:

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) { ...
```

to

```
$('#pageId').bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) { ...
```

Comment: For me the event doesn't get triggered when inserting the pageId using v1.0...(also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793403/jquery-mobile-cant-bind-pagebeforechange-to-page-id)

Comment: binding to pageId doesn't fire the event

Comment: @JihoKang if you post a question with some of the code you're using, would probably be easier to help you this way

Comment: @Phill, awesome, nowhere in documentation does it mention this deviation between single / multiple page layouts. Thanks.

Comment: @Phill: Tried it, does not bind to the id either :-(

Comment: @IanWarner you do realize that the example is for jQM 1.0 and there have been a ton of changes since then ...

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little late, but here's my educated guess:

Any pagechange event triggers two transitions, one "forward" (pagechange) and one "backward" (hashchange). If you go forward, the hashChange is blocked, if you backward, it's the other way around.

Look into the jqm source code and check the **ignoreNextHashChange** property.

This is responsible for blocking the hashChange on forward transitions, otherwise you'd be going back and forth.

I guess your function is firing twice, because both events are both triggered from inside changePage and hashChange.

If that was the case, JQM would have to block the hashChange rountine before triggering this event.

Comment: I'm giving you a point since this is helpful advice, but I actually figured out the problem quite some time ago :-). The problem had to do preventDefault() not running while still manually calling a page change. I had a method with an AJAX call in it above the preventDefault() and an error with the AJAX wasn't being properly handled and the preventDefault() never got called. Silly mistake, but it was driving me crazy after staring at it for 6 hours. Really just needed another set of eyes to tell me what I kept skipping over. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It gets called twice by design. http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/

if `data.toPage` is set to a string, the event indicates that navigation is about to commence.

if `data.toPage` is set to a jQuery object, the event indicates that the destination page has been loaded.

Comment: Read the question. The code posted shows filtering on (typeof data.toPage === "string"). The event is shown to be passing that conditional twice. This issue is more complex.

Comment: this is useful information for those who don't know this, but because of the way it was phrased i'm not going to upvote it back to zero

Answer (score -1):

If you read jquery mobile documentation https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/ , it says it is called twice, once data.toPage being url to new page, second time data.toPage being already jquery object of new page.