# jQuery Mobile - Manipulating the DOM - Refreshing a page

Tags: jquery-mobile

This whole jQuery mobile dynamic data (pulling data from the server) is driving me nuts. Why should it be this difficult to manipulate the DOM and the refresh the page?

I have my page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="intranet-holidays" data-title="HOLIDAYS" data-add-back-btn="true"></div>
```

In document.ready I have the following:

```
$( document ).delegate( "#intranet-holidays", "pagebeforecreate", function() {
   $('body').addClass('ui-loading');
   $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Loading Holidays...";
   $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
   // calls getJSON to retrieve data from the web server
   loadHolidays();
});
```

When my data returns back from the server I add collapsible DIVs into my page (intranet-holidays).

Inside of the collapsible DIVs I have some ULs.

I know my syntax is correct because I can grab the generated HTML, save it to a file, then display that file and it all shows correctly. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Here is what my dynamically loaded page looks like (not what I want):

[image]

I know that I can refresh a listview with the following:

```
$('#list').listview('refresh');
```

That works great for a list.

**How do I refresh the page (that contains collapsible DIVs and those collapsible DIVs contains ULs)?**

Yes, I want all the data in the page to be dynamic.

Comment: Related to your $(document).delegate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761859/jquery-mobile-pagebeforechange-being-called-twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `success` handler method of the AJAX call that fetches the JSON data,add `$('#intranet-holidays').trigger('create');` after you create  the lists.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days. That did it!!

Comment: Is this also supposed to work when you REMOVE an element from the DOM?  I can't get it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#page').trigger('create');
```

Or read:

http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/02/dynamically-appending-elements-to.html

Comment: I have tried that. Where should I place that call? I have it in the pagebeforecreate right after the call to loadHolidays(). It doesn't make a difference. That URL you provide is dealing with listview's. I have read and re-read that URL. This is for a page.

Comment: $('#intranet-holidays').trigger('create'); after loadHolidays() doesn't work?

Comment: No, it does not work. I have tried that more than once before coming here to stackoverflow. And just to be clear I'm point to the latest version of jQuery mobile.

Comment: Is this also supposed to work when you REMOVE an element from the DOM?  I can't get it to.