# jQuery Mobile - can't bind pagebeforechange to page id?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I could only ever bind pagebeforechange to the entire jquery mobile document, not an individual page.  Can anyone explain why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kenw232/HYzYJ/) doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't fire because the page doesn't reload or change. Look at the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html).

Comment: I have the same issue - "pagebeforechange" doesn't work when bound directly to page while "pagebeforeshow" and "pagebeforecreate" work properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div[data-role='page']").live( "pagebeforehide", function( event ) {
alert('This alert should trigger before Next Page Here is shown?');
});
```

(check the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HYzYJ/48/) for details)
you can also use bind instead of live  , Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery Mobile - I'm pretty certain you don't bind to the document, but to the pageinit property.

Binding to the doc would create issues... keep in mind for this link to work on #home again you will need another event listener for [beforepageshow](http://jsfiddle.net/tommyAwesome/L5SqS/) or what you before the page is shown again.

[This](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) doc is very helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Selector for JQM pages:

```
$('.ui-page')
```

Adding the event listener to all the pages in the document can be done as:

```
$(document).delegate(".ui-page","pagebeforehide", function(evt, ui){
   alert('pagebeforehide fired');
}
```

Fiddle using **[delegate](http://jsfiddle.net/7KBTJ/)**:

Note using **bind** instead of **delegate** will NOT work for the aforementioned selector as ui-page class is added only on page creation.

In-order to use **bind**, use the following selector:

```
$("div[data-role='page']")
```

And add the event listener using(only after document is ready or body has loaded):

```
$("div[data-role='page']").bind("pagebeforehide", function(evt, ui{
alert('pagebeforehide fired');
}
```

Fiddle using **[bind](http://jsfiddle.net/NaEKf/)**:

I also recommend using mobileinit event rather document ready!

Comment: As of jQuery Mobile 1.1.0, your solution with bind works with 'pagebeforeshow' but not with 'pagebeforechange'. I dont get it.

Comment: -1. Read question carefully - It was asked about "pagebeforechange", not "pagebeforehide" event. None of your examples are working with "pagebeforechange".

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the exact same problem, but I at least have a work-around for you. Warning: this is stupid, horrible code. *But it does the job.*

```
window.doubleLoadPreventer = 0;

$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){

    if ( window.doubleLoadPreventer === 1 ) {
        window.doubleLoadPreventer = 0;
        return;
    } else {
        window.doubleLoadPreventer = 1;
    }

    //your normal event handler code here
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fire at all, but not twice.